# npm install: Error: 405 Method Not Allowed - GET dependency

Tags: angular, npm, proxy, artifactory

I'm having a trouble, when doing npm install in my project I get the following error on every dependency which npm try to download from my private artifactory repo:

```
Error: 405 Method Not Allowed - GET dependency
```

I'm behing a corporate proxy, so I use a provided pac file to me and the following .npmrc configuration as you can see:

```
proxy=http://pac-file-url
https-proxy=http://pac-file-url
https_proxy=http://pac-file-url
strict-ssl=false
registry=https://private-repository-url
always-auth=true
_auth=password
```

Can somebody know if is there something wrong with npmrc configuration or it can be for something different?

Thank you